# How to disable printing touch events data in Flutter

Tags: flutter

When I am working on my flutter app, the app always prints every touch I do on the screen. I am printing a lot of things and it is kind of hard to find my data inside this mess. Can this option be disabled?

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50808#issuecomment-700903178 this may help

Answer (score 0):

This problem solved in Android Studio by :

File > Settings > Editor > General > Console

Look for section: "Fold console lines that contain"

Click the "+" button on right hand side of scrollable list

Add your substring of what you'd like hidden from the Console output.
For example in Flutter, I removed "D/" (without "") or "I/Flutter"(without "") or  which are your emulator most common print debug messages.

Comment: is there something similar for vs code